# Change array object value in react native with textInput and function component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hello guys I wanna ask about change Array Value when I type in text input in react native

```
const [rad, setRad] = useState([
  { value: 'a', status: false, title: 'ab },
  { value: 'b', status: false, title: 'ac' },
  { value: 'c', status: false, title: 'ad' },
]);


<TextInput 
  numberOfLines={2} 
  placeholder="note"
  onChangeText={(text) => setRad([...rad[3], { value: text }])}
/>
```

but when I type an error screen comes up and the message 'Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method'

What should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to update the third item on your array state `rad` with `[..rad[3], { value:  text}]`. Can you clarify what you want to update  all of the values of each object or a specific object based some `id` or `title`. 

More context on what you're trying to achieve would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The initial state is an array of length 3, i.e. with indices 0, 1, and 2, so attempting to spread `...rad[3]` is the code attempting to spread the ***fourth*** element, which is an undefined value.

You likely meant to spread the previous `rad` state array instead into the new array reference and append the new text value. When updating arrays in React state it's recommended to use a functional state update to ensure updating from the previous state and not the value of state closed over in any callback/handler scopes.

```
<TextInput 
  numberOfLines={2} 
  placeholder="note"
  onChangeText={(text) => setRad(rad => [...rad, { value: text }])}
/>
```